# No change in heap?

Tags: c, malloc

I wrote a simple function in order to check if malloc works. I create 1 Gb array, fill it with numbers, but the heap does not seem to change. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>  // For assert()
#include <stdlib.h>  // For malloc(), free() and realloc()
#include <unistd.h>  // For sleep()

static void create_array_in_heap()
{
    double* b;
    b = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
    assert(b != NULL);    // Check that the allocation succeeded

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<1024*1024*1024; i++);
        b[i] = 1;

    sleep(10);

    free(b);
}

int main()
{
    create_array_in_heap();

    return 0;
}
```

[screenshot of Linux' system monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFM5M.png)
[image: screenshot of Linux' system monitor]

Any ideas why ?

Comment: Remove the semicolon after your loop.

Comment: Thanks! Made a typo...

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: a simpler explanation is given in the comments. But my answer applies once the `;` [has been removed](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sI2DTb).

An agressive optimizing compiler, such as Clang ([Compiler Explorer link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8R6WiJ)), can see that the only important part of your function `create_array_in_heap` is the call to `sleep`. The rest has no functional value, since you only fill a memory block to eventually discard it, and is removed by the compiler. This is the entirety of your program compiled by Clang 7.0.0 with `-O2`:

```
main:                                   # @main
        pushq   %rax
        movl    $10, %edi
        callq   sleep
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        popq    %rcx
        retq
```

In order to benchmark any aspect of a program, the program should have been designed to output a result (computing and discarding the result is too easy for the compiler to optimize into nothing). The result should also be computed from inputs that aren't known at compile-time, otherwise the computation always produces the same result and can be optimized by constant propagation.

Comment: Ok thanks for your tips. Apparently I made a typo (thanks tkausl for noticing) behind the for loop where I fill the array with numbers. However, if the semicolon is removed, than what is the result of Clang 7.0.0 with -O2 ? Is it still the same ? I guess not ?

Comment: @Meerkat I have edited my answer (at the top) to point out that Clang's output is the same in this case. Also note that I have provided Compiler Explorer links that allow you to modify the program or the compiler yourself, and see the results instantly.

Comment: But is the compiler not a bit too agressive in this case ? I guess this is assembler language (compiler explorer) ? Do you maybe have a link to a pdf where assembler is being explained into more detail ?

Comment: @Meerkat No, the compiler is not being too agressive in this case (although there are some variations of it where it's possible to argue that Clang is going too far). There is absolutely no guarantee in C that any useless computation in the source code is translated to a corresponding useless computation in the assembly produced by the compiler. On the contrary, the compilers' goal is to produce the fasted code the behavior of which is undistinguishable from that indicated by the source code. If producing faster code means not making some calls to `malloc`, `malloc` will not be called.